# How to disable mouse wheel click in a div?

Tags: jquery, css, html, drag, mousewheel

I'm building an application for my client and I cannot figure out how to disable mouse wheel click in a div. I know you can do it because I've done it before but totally forgot it. 
Basically, when I hover my mouse over a div, and I click using the mouse wheel and then drag the mouse down, it basically drag down my whole page. Is there a way to just disable the whole action of mouse wheel clicking and then dragging?

Comment: Using chrome debugger, I see there is a mousewheel event litener. can't get it to trigger though

Comment: just simply add mouse wheel event handler dummy function and discard the event. http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-javascript-mouse-wheel/

Comment: Hmm, chrome logs this wheel click event as a regular mousedown event

Comment: jQuery normalizes the `mousewheel click` to `2` under `e.which`.

Comment: return true to tell that you have processed it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click', function(e){
    if(e.which == 2){
        e.preventDefault(); //stop default click action from mousewheel
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XzEVn/)

Simply replace `document` the selector for the div in question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For some odd reason, this doesn't work in my application. And yes, this was the same thing I was doing before to stop this action and it worked on my previous applications but not this one. I think something might be wrong with my CSS. My div element has a fixed position, with 100% height, z-index function and overflow is hidden in it.

Comment: @Adrian Please post the relevant HTML into a jsFiddle so I can better tackle this issue.

Comment: Any viable solution so far guys?